# How to iterate a lists in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-oci

I have a code

```
resource "oci_core_security_list" "db_security_list" {
  count          = var.deploy_database ? 1 : 0
  compartment_id = var.network_compartment_id
  vcn_id         = var.vcn_id
  freeform_tags  = { "Component" = "Database" }
  display_name   = "test-db-sl"
  ingress_security_rules {
    protocol = "6" # TCP
    source   = var.compute_subnet_cidr
    tcp_options {
      max = "1522"
      min = "1522"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently the `compute_subnet_cidr` is having a single subnet cidr block

how can I iterate the if the compute_subnet_cidr is a list.

```
compute_subnet_cidr  = ["10.10.10.0/24", "10.10.10.1/24", "10.10.10.2/24"]
```

How can I change the above code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
resource "oci_core_security_list" "db_security_list" {
  count          = var.deploy_database ? 1 : 0
  compartment_id = var.network_compartment_id
  vcn_id         = var.vcn_id
  freeform_tags  = { "Component" = "Database" }
  display_name   = "test-db-sl"

  dynamic "ingress_security_rules" {    
      for_each   = var.compute_subnet_cidr
      content {
        protocol = "6" # TCP
        source   = ingress_security_rules.value
        tcp_options {
          max = "1522"
          min = "1522"
        }
     }
   }  

}
```

Comment: It gives me error : ```│     │ var.compute_subnet_cidr is tuple with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "source": string required.
╵```

Comment: @cloudbud What did you changed? why would `var.compute_subnet_cidr` be a tuple with 2 elements? In your question it has different structure.

Comment: `compute_subnet_cidr  = ["10.10.10.0/24", "10.10.10.1/24"]`  this is my var

Comment: @cloudbud Are you sure you used my code exactly as I wrote? Seems to me that you are using its old version or you changed something?

Comment: Yes I am using your code only

Comment: I just added this list in the  tfvars

Comment: @cloudbud can you please check with `for_each = toset(var.compute_subnet_cidr)`?

Comment: Its still not working

Comment: │ Inappropriate value for attribute "source": string required.

Comment: What is the full definition of your `compute_subnet_cidr`? Did you set any type for it?

Comment: I edited the answer to `source   = ingress_security_rules.value`. If this does not work, I don't know what can be causing your error.

Comment: no type is set still the same error

Comment: @cloudbud Then I have no idea how you could get such an error based on your info given in the question. There must be something that is not shown.

Comment: @cloudbud Did you try with `source   = ingress_security_rules.value`?